# Solving T(n) = 9T(n / 10) + log^3 n?

Tags: math, big-o, recurrence

I have the recurrence

> T(n) = 9T(n/10) + log<sup>3</sup> n

and I'm trying to find its complexity .

After i-substitutions I can see that

> T(i) = 9T(n / 10<sup>i+1</sup>) + log<sup>3</sup>(n / 10<sup>i</sup>).

I don't know how to continue, however. How do I solve this recurrence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A technique that is sometimes useful for solving recurrences like these is to both upper- and lower-bound the recurrence with two simpler recurrences and to see what you find.

For example, notice that your recurrence

> T(n) = 9T(n / 10) + log<sup>3</sup> n

is lower-bounded by the recurrence

> L(n) = 9L(n / 10) + 1.

This recurrence can be directly solved using the Master Theorem. There are many different formulations of the Master Theorem, but my favorite is the one that solves recurrences of the form

> T(n) = aT(n / b) + n<sup>d</sup>

for constants a, b, and d. In this case, we have a = 9, b = 10, and d = 0, and since log<sub>b</sub> a > d, it means that the recurrence solves to L(n) = Θ(n<sup>log<sub>10</sub>9</sup>). This means that we know your recurrence is at least Ω(n<sup>log<sub>10</sub>9</sup>).

Similarly, notice that your recurrence is upper-bounded by

> U(n) = 9U(n / 10) + n<sup>ε</sup>

for any fixed ε > 0, since any polynomial term dominates any constant power of a logarithmic term. Let's imagine that ε is very, very small. What does the Master Theorem say in this case? Here, we have a = 9, b = 10, and d = ε. Assuming that ε is indeed very, very small, we'll have that log<sub>b</sub> a > ε, and so the recurrence solves to Θ(n<sup>log<sub>10</sub>9</sup>).

This shows that your recurrence is nicely sandwiched between two other recurrences that are Ω(n<sup>log<sub>10</sub>9</sup>) and O(n<sup>log<sub>10</sub>9</sup>), respectively, so your recurrence solves to **Θ(n<sup>log<sub>10</sub>9</sup>)**.

To summarize:

- If you have a recurrence with an unusual function term added in, you can sometimes solve that recurrence by upper- and lower-bounding it with recurrences with simpler additive terms.
- Logarithms are lower-bounded by constants and upper-bounded by any (positive, constant-power) polynomial.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Damn, I made a leap-of-faith by assuming that the logarithmic terms wouldn't cancel after computing the summations, and forgot to check the result against the Master Theorem... clearly that didn't pay off, and anyway your verbose explanation seems more intuitive for OP. +1

Answer (score 0):

use master method to solve the problem

It solves the recurrences of form T(n) = aT(n/b) + f(n).

Master Method is a direct way to get the solution. The master method works only for following type of recurrences or for recurrences that can be transformed to following type.

T(n) = aT(n/b) + f(n) where a >= 1 and b > 1
There are following three cases:
1. If f(n) = Θ(nc) where c < Logba then T(n) = Θ(nLogba)

2. If f(n) = Θ(nc) where c = Logba then T(n) = Θ(ncLog n)

3.If f(n) = Θ(nc) where c > Logba then T(n) = Θ(f(n))

.it is used to solve recurrences in functions like T(n) = aT(n/b) + f(n) where a >= 1 and b > 1
same as yours

Comment: I know about the master theorem but I'm trying to solve the problem using substitutions or a recursion tree . I would appreciate your help if possible.